# Can't find and process text taken out of an HTML

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to search in a webpage the "spanish" content but can't get it at all.

This is the code I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'http://www.autotaskstatus.net/'
r = requests.get(url)
estado = r.status_code
r = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
data = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'name'})[1]
pais = 'Spanish'
data.get_text()
print(data.text)
```

I have there the "pais" var so it will be replaced by an input so the user can search the country they want.
The only data I get with a 1 there is "Limited Release" but if I go with a 0 I can't filter the results at all

I have been searching all over Internet and couldn't find anyone with this same problem so I can't find a solution.

I am using Python 3.6

**Edit:** since people seemed to find this unclear I'll explain it now
What I have on the page is: - just a part

```
<div data-component-id="fp5s6cp13l47"
     class="component-inner-container status-green "
     data-component-status="operational"
     data-js-hook="">


    <span class="name">
      Concord
      &nbsp;
    </span>

      <span class="tooltip-base tool" title="https://concord.centrastage.net">?</span>
    <span class="component-status">
      Operational
    </span>
```

So spanish is like "Concord" and what I want to take out is the "Spanish" (and later on the "operational") which will be in a var so it can later be changed for any country there

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to get from that website? Those scheduled maintenance updates? And how do you know it is Spanish? By having 'ES ZONE' in the header?

Comment: That web has a "Spanish" server so since every single country has "name" as a class which is annoying, I thought about searching inside the web instead of searching with the tags since all of them are exactly the same and the program won't know which one to get

What I wanted to get was the "status" - if it is operational, so that is why I was trying to start by getting the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Spanish server status using this approach:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'http://www.autotaskstatus.net/'
with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}
    r = s.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    data = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'component-inner-container'})
    pais = 'Spanish'
    print([d.find('span', {'class': 'name'}).text.strip() + ' - ' + d.find('span', {'class': 'component-status'}).text.strip() for d in data if pais in d.text])
```

Comment: That only gets a list with all the countries though